# UIViewControllerのサブクラスを呼び出す際に、必要な変数が初期化されてなければビルドエラーにするには

Tags: swift

あるViewControllerからwebviewを持ったmyWebViewControllerを呼び出すとします。その際に任意のURLを渡します。以下の様なコードです。

```
let myWebViewController = MyWebViewController()
myWebViewController.url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!
self.navigationController?.showViewController(myWebViewController, sender: nil)
```

もしこの場合、urlが渡されなかったとしてもビルドエラーは発生しません。

```
//これでもビルドエラーは起きない
let myWebViewController = MyWebViewController()
self.navigationController?.showViewController(myWebViewController, sender: nil)
```

urlがnilのままでも、実行されるまで気づく事が出来ません。

これを防ぐためには、どのような書き方が適切でしょうか？
urlに何かしらのNSURL型がセットされる事を強制したいです。

サンプルコードはこちらに
https://github.com/nishiyamaosamu/myWebViewSample

swift:2.1
xcode:7.1.1

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記のように、イニシャライザで`url`パラメータを渡すのを強制するのはどうでしょうか？その上で他のイニシャライザは使えないように、`@available(*, unavailable)`を指定して、コンパイル時にチェックされるようにします。

```
init(url: String) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    ...
}

@available(*, unavailable)
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。おかげさまで、目的の実装ができそうです。あわせてご教授頂けると助かるのですが、storyboardを使用して初期化した場合にも、同様の目的を達成する方法はありますでしょうか？
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "MyWebView", bundle: nil)
        let myWebViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! MyWebViewController

Comment: Storyboardやxibからインスタンス化する場合は`init?(coder:)`が呼ばれてしまうので無理ですね。諦めて実行時にエラーが出るので良しとするか、urlに初期値を設定して、決してurlがnilにならないようにする、あたりが妥当だと思います。